# Professional way to handle model classes when using GSON and SQLight Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, gson, ormlite

In My application I get data from a web service and display those data in recycler view. After that I'm planing to add those data in to local sqlite database and display those data when user open application without internet connection.

Here's a simple model class I'm using to pars JSON result using GSON

```
public class Repo implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.url);
    }

    public Repo() {
    }

    protected Repo(Parcel in) {
        this.id = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.url = in.readString();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public static final Creator<Repo> CREATOR = new Creator<Repo>() {
        @Override
        public Repo createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Repo(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Repo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Repo[size];
        }
    };
}
```

I can create a almost identical model class to represent SQLite data. In here I'm using ORMlite. But this is very similar situation for other ORMs.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = Repo.TABLE_NAME)
public class Repo {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "repo";

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "repo_id")
    private long repoId;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    private String name;

    public long getRepoId() {
        return repoId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setRepoId(long repoId) {
        this.repoId = repoId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

But by the time I'm trying to save these data in to SQLite database I already have data objects set in GSON model classes. It's kind a redundant thing copy object from GSON model and setting that values in to SQLite model. So I came up with below solution by trying to use single model class to represent both.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = Repo.TABLE_NAME)
public class Repo implements Parcelable {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "repo";

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "repo_id")
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.url);
    }

    public Repo() {
    }

    protected Repo(Parcel in) {
        this.id = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.url = in.readString();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public static final Creator<Repo> CREATOR = new Creator<Repo>() {
        @Override
        public Repo createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Repo(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Repo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Repo[size];
        }
    };
}
```

I have try this with different type of model class where it only had `String` type fields. Since GSON uses types like `Integer`,`Boolean` That stopping me from using same model for SQLite because database does not identify `Integer` as a type, in order to work it need to be `int`.

So what is the professional way to handle this ? Don't I have any other option other than going back to the method of creating two separate model class to represent SQLite and GSON.

Comment: *Since GSON uses Primitive types like Integer,Boolean* `Integer` is not primitive type, neither `Boolean` ... define *database does not identify Integer*  ... SQLite knows nothing about java types

Comment: Thank you for point in it out. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yout approach is absolutely correct, but i think you are putting too much effort reinventing the wheel

You can easily achieve the described task using [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)